# UITapGestureRecognizer issue in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, uitapgesturerecognizer

I guys,

today I've updated my iPhone to iOS 9 and now have problems with a gesture recognizer.
This is the error:

> WARNING: A Gesture recognizer (; target=
>   <(action=onVideoTap:, target=)>>)
>   was setup in a storyboard/xib to be added to more than one view
>   (->; layer = >) at a time, this was never allowed, and is now enforced.
>   Beginning with iOS 9.0 it will be put in the first view it is loaded
>   into.

I didn't have this problem with iOS8.
The view contains a UIImageView and a TextView. The recognizer was dropped into the ImageView and has only referncing outlets to this view.

I don't really understand this issue.
Can somebody help me? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already fixed it.
The storyboard is localized and in one language I assigned the the recognizer twice to the picture view.
Somehow this seemed to cause troubles on the other storyboards too.

Comment: im facing the same issue..what do you mean by you assigned it twice to the picture view..can you please explain..will be really helpful

Comment: One recognizer can anly be assigned to one other component. For me, I assigned the same recognizer to the picture view twice. Just have a look at the recognizer and see to which other components it's reffering

Comment: This is unfortunate - I've encountered the same problem because I've purposely been using the same gesture recognizer on multiple components, which seems like a reasonable thing to do. I guess this means if I want to attach the same behavior to multiple objects then instead of using a single gesture recognizer I need to create multiple gesture recognizers. Feels inefficient to me.

Answer (score 13):

This was happening with me because I wanted to use a **Tap Gesture Recognize** with an image in a `TableViewCell` contained in a `TableView`.

### The problem is that:

I add one **Tap Gesture Recognizer** but I have more than one `TableViewCell` (more than one image) in my table.

iOS will assign the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the first image in the first cell, and other cells will be without gestures (the gesture already set to the first image only).

### To Solve this problem follow this:

1. Make sure you checked `User Interaction Enabled` for the `UIView` you want to assign with a `TapRecognizerGesture`.
2. in the sub-view `TableViewCell` in my case add a new `UITapGestureRecognizer`. The code:

   ```
   internal let tapRecognizer1: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()`
   ```
3. In your main view `TableView` in my case and for every cell assign the `UITapGestureRecognizer` you made with each cell to a main function in the main view:

   ```
   cell.tapRecognizer1.addTarget(self, action: "img_Click:")
   cell.img.gestureRecognizers = []
   cell.img.gestureRecognizers!.append(cell.tapRecognizer1)
   ```
4. Add the function you want `UITapGestureRecognizer` to fire when clicked:

   ```
   func img_Click(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       print("ok")
   }
   ```

### Notes:

- You can use simple way if you do not want the `UITapGestureRecognizer` action in the main view by assigning it in its sub-view directly.
- in step 4 function name must be the same as in `addTarget` line.

Comment: I had to use the following code when adding the target to the recognizer: `cell.tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedController.imageTap(_:)))`

Comment: @GustavoStraube Yes you are right, This upgrade had been released in the new `swift`, But the older one has the same as I answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I think that this problem happen when you use storyboard added a Tap Gesture Recognizer. Because some reasons you added more than one views.(see the picture).

[image]

So, delete other wrong views,leave the right one view.

[image]

Comment: It worked for me, xcode doesn't give any feedback when we connect gesture recognizer to a view.